# Classification Report - Precision and F-score are ill-defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I imported classification_report from sklearn.metrics and when I enter my `np.arrays` as parameters I get the following error :

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135:
>   UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and
>   being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.   'precision',
>   'predicted', average, warn_for)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1137:
>   UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall and F-score are ill-defined and being
>   set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples.   'recall', 'true',
>   average, warn_for)

Here is the code :

```
svclassifier_polynomial = SVC(kernel = 'poly', degree = 7, C = 5)

svclassifier_polynomial.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier_polynomial.predict(X_test)


poly = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
```

When I was not using np.array in the past it worked just fine, any ideas on how i can correct this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not an error, just a **warning** that not all your labels are included in your `y_pred`, i.e. there are some labels in your `y_test` that your classifier never predicts.

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, f1_score, classification_report

y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2] # 3-class problem
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] # we never predict '2'

precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro') 
[...] UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. 
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
0.16666666666666666

precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro') # no warning
0.3333333333333333

precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None) 
[...] UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. 
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
array([0.5, 0. , 0. ])
```

Exact same warnings are produced for `f1_score` (not shown).

Practically this only warns you that in the `classification_report`, the respective values for labels with no predicted samples (here `2`) will be set to 0:

```
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))


              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.50      1.00      0.67         2
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00         2
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00         2

   micro avg       0.33      0.33      0.33         6
   macro avg       0.17      0.33      0.22         6
weighted avg       0.17      0.33      0.22         6

[...] UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. 
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

> When I was not using np.array in the past it worked just fine

Highly doubtful, since in the example above I have used simple Python lists, and not Numpy arrays...

Comment: I understand this warning is because some classes in the test never get predicted. What I don't understand is a way to understand why a classification algorithm may behave such way. For example, I fitted an `SVC` and a `RF` classifiers on same data, `RF` doesn't predict a particular class in all runs of experiments.

Comment: @arilwan there are dozens of reasons why a classification algorithm may behave this way, and this was not the question here. Please open a new question with the details, but be reminded that SO questions should be about *programming*, *not* about ML theory and methodology - see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 3):

It means that some labels are only present in train data and some labels are only present in test dataset. Run the following codes, to understand the distribution of train and test labels.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(y_train)
Counter(y_test)
```

Use stratified train_test_split to get rid of the situation where some labels are present only in test dataset.

It might have worked in past simply because of the random splitting of dataset. Hence, stratified splitting is always recommended.

The first situation is more about model fine tuning or choice of model.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that, if I get this error even when using a stratified split, I should try to increase the dataset and/or adjust the model's hyper params in order to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you use Seqeval?

I got a similar problem when using Seqeval pakcage to compute metrics. It turned out that when I used mono-character labels like 'U' or '0' for NER, the `seqeval/metrics/sequence_labeling.py` script truncates a letter during processing, so the labels taken for comparison are empty. Changing the labels to 'UU' and '00' solved the problem.